# Issue displaying PDF figures created with R on iOS devices

Tags: ios, pdf, r, ggplot2

I'm making some plots in R. The resulting PDFs don't display properly on iOS devices like the iPhone. For example, here's a stock ggplot2 figure created as a PDF:

```
library(ggplot2)
mpg.eg <- within(mpg[1:74,], {
  model <- reorder(model, cty)
  manufacturer <- reorder(manufacturer, -cty)
})

pdf(file="figures/ios-example.pdf")
p <- qplot(cty, model, data=mpg.eg)
p + facet_grid(manufacturer ~ ., scales="free", space="free") +
  opts(strip.text.y = theme_text())
dev.off()
```

When viewed on an iPhone, the dots in the dotplot are not displayed. See, e.g., [the resulting pdf](http://kieranhealy.org/files/misc/ios-example.pdf) if you're on an iOS device.

I understand from reading the docs that this is most likely a problem with limited font availability and the vagaries of PDF rendering on iOS, not an issue with pdf creation in R. I had thought that maybe embedding fonts in the PDF with

```
embedFonts("figures/ios-example.pdf")
```

would sort things out, but it doesn't. Is there something I can do to work around this iOS issue beyond just making the figure available in some other format?

Comment: Hi Kieran. If the documented can be view on a 'real' computer then the issue is probably with the iOS viewer.  Would switching to non-pdf formats be an alternative?

Comment: Hi Dirk, yes, they can be viewed on a regular computer --- as you can see from the question I was basically certain the docs were right and it was an iOS/iPhone issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`embedFonts` by default doesn't embed the standard PDF font set, and therefore doesn't actually make any significant changes to your example PDF.  Try instead

```
embedFonts("figures/ios-example.pdf",
           options="-dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true")
```

and if *that* doesn't work, tack "`-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer`" on there too.

[EDIT August 2020: With current versions of R, another thing to try is switching from the `pdf` device to the `cairo_pdf` device. `cairo_pdf` uses a more sophisticated library for PDF generation and, among other things, it embeds fonts itself.]

For what it's worth, though, your example is displayed correctly on the only iOS device I have to hand (iPad, OS version 4.2.1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your solution works with the `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` option added to the other two. I have access to 4.2.1 on an iPhone 3GS rather than an iPad, and it was definitely failing there.

Comment: I also had to set `-dUseCIEColor`. OMG, that's quite annoying to require this "post-processing" with ghostscript (even if R does the job for you), I guess I just won't use ggplot2 anymore.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try telling R not to use the Dingbats font to draw points: `pdf(..., useDingbats = F)`

Comment: I would have thought this to be the "correct" answer for the iOS target platform. Embedding fonts can really add bulk to file sizes.

Comment: True, but on the other hand, `embedFonts` runs the PDF through Ghostscript which means the actual content stream is now compressed and (IIRC) redundant drawing operators are removed, unlike what R itself does.  That could easily more than make up for the size of the fonts.